# How do I randomly choose between two enum values from a seperate class file

Tags: java, random, enums

So I need to create one class with an enum in it, then use a second class to randomly select one of those enum values and do that as many times as the user wants.

Here's the main code

```
while (loop){
    System.out.println("Enter the number of times you want to toss the coin, enter '0' to end the program: ");
    num = s.nextInt(); 

    int tails = 0;
    int heads = 0;

      if (num == 0){
      loop = false;
      continue;
      }
      else if (num < 0){
      System.out.println("That's a negative number");
      continue;
      }



       for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
       {
        if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
            tails = tails + 1;
        else
            heads = heads + 1;
      }

      System.out.println("Heads: " + heads + " Tails: " + tails);
      }
```

and then here's the enum code

```
    public class Coin{

public enum CoinEnum {
        HEADS,TAILS;
    }
}
```

I cut out some stuff because it was unneeded.
I think I have the general idea on how to randomly select, you can see I already wrote a quick calculation on how to do if there wasn't an enum value but I have no idea how to access the enum values from my main program, I tried making the class a package but that didn't work, I'm just not sure how. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Don't nest `CoinEnum` within a class.  Give it its own source file.  That will make it easier to reference it from some other class.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work - randomly generate HEAD or TAIL enum; comments added to the code. Edited to change this to a working standalone example.

```
public class CoinEnumDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // print 10 random values
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int val = (int) Math.round(Math.random());
            System.out.println(CoinEnum.values()[val]);
        }
    }

        enum CoinEnum {
            HEAD, TAIL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting the error that the program can't find the variable CoinEnum, don't I need to input it somewhere?

Comment: The program is supposed to take the enum from a different class file, not the same file. It's supposed to use two different files, not one.

Comment: ok, then you will need to import CoinEnum; assuming that you know about access modifiers in Java.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up, I don't know about access modifiers